Как правильно отображать символы PUA и EUDC в WPF?
Я работаю над приложением WPF (.NET 8), которому нужно отображать специальные символы из PUA (Private Use Area) и EUDC (Extended User Defined Characters). Однако у меня возникают проблемы с их корректным отображением. Символы либо вообще не появляются, либо отображаются некорректно.
Если я устанавливаю шрифт таким образом:
<TextBox FontFamily="C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\EUDC.TTE#EUDC" FontSize="23" />

то он отображается корректно. Однако это кажется мне странным решением. Этот метод не работает с RichEdit. Есть ли другой способ отображения символов EUDC?
<Window
    x:Class="FONTTESTWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock
                Margin="7"
                FontSize="18"
                Text="RichTextBox:" />

            <!--  Не отображает символы  -->
            <RichTextBox
                Margin="7,0,7,0"
                FontFamily="C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\EUDC.TTE#EUDC"
                FontSize="23" />

            <TextBlock
                Margin="7"
                FontSize="18"
                Text="TextBox:" />

            <!--  Отображает символы  -->
            <TextBox
                Margin="7,0,7,0"
                FontFamily="C:\\WINDOWS\\FONTS\\EUDC.TTE#EUDC"
                FontSize="23" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>



У меня в системе не находит ваш символ. В чармапе нет никакого Private Characters. Как воспроизвести то что вы пытаетесь сделать? Кстати, вот способ встраивания шрифта, вдруг пригодится. Ещё непонятно, для чего вам ричбокс, его крайне редко используют.

Ну, как бы очевидно, что для отображения специальных символов нужен специальный шрифт. А вот почему это не работает в RichEdit - непонятно.

@aepot Нужно добавить пользовательский символ, вот тут указано как это сделать.
Что касательно необходимости ричбокса, то это просто рабочая задача которую надо попробовать реализовать.

Глянул поверхностно, внутри ричбокса живёт <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" ... />, внутри него в разметке контрола ничего нет, но после запуска туда добавляется FlowDocumentView. Дальше можно в рантайме поковыряться, как работает именно FlowDocumentView и почему он не цепляет ваш шрифт, то есть проблема шрифта это не проблема самого ричбокса, а FlowDocumentView, живущего внутри. Ричбокс доставляет шрифт до вложенного контрола своими стилями нормально.

@aepot спасибо за совет, поковыряю FlowDocumentView, но еще интересно почему в WinForms это все работает из коробки, а в WPF приходится искать разные изощеренные метод ?
Т.е. в WinForms нет необходимость задавать этот шрифт где-либо. Символы из EUDC подтягиваются автоматически.

Я 30 лет винду знаю, и только от вас про эти символы узнал. Которые по сути бесполезны, так как вносятся только в файлы текущей системы. Есть полно шрифтов с готовыми иконками, есть встроенные в винду, есть SVG иконки, которые можно рисовать самому в векторе, и не пикселями. Растровая графика для шрифтов и иконок устарела. Вероятно поэтому в WPF об этом уже никто не заморачивался. Тем более, любую картинку можно вставить прямо в тот же FlowDocument без каких-либо доработок и шрифтов.
